# MariaDB not listening on 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

This is the MariaDB/MySQL version on my VPS running Ubuntu 16.04:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

This is probably the relevant content of `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`:

```
  1 #
  2 # These groups are read by MariaDB server.
  3 # Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
  4 #
  5 # See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
  6 #
  7 
  8 # this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
  9 [server]
 10 
 11 # this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
 12 [mysqld]
 13 
 14 #
 15 # * Basic Settings
 16 #
 17 user    = mysql
 18 pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 19 socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 20 port    = 3306
 21 basedir   = /usr
 22 datadir   = /var/lib/mysql
 23 tmpdir    = /tmp
 24 lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
 25 skip-external-locking
 26 
 27 # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
 28 # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
 29 bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 #This is line changed by me from 127.0.0.1
 30
```

After using `systemctl stop mysql` and `systemctl start mysql`, this is still my `netstat -nat |grep :3306`'s output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:54316         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58456         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58466         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58458         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58454         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58460         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58444         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58452         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58446         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58462         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58464         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58450         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:58468         ESTABLISHED
```

As you can see in the first line, its still listening on `127.0.0.1`, and not on `0.0.0.0`. Where am I possibly going wrong? TIA

Comment: Just for the record: http://serverfault.com/questions/257513/how-bad-is-setting-mysqls-bind-address-to-0-0-0-0

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks, I'm aware about it. I just want to connect two different VPS on same MySQL instance, present on 2 different IP addresses. For the rest I plan on using firewall :)

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks again, I ended up doing this with SSH tunnel :)

Comment: I got same problem with MariaDB on Linux Mint (same maria version, same config, same netstat result). Any other solution except SSH tunnel?

Comment: It's not a good solution for production environment, but enough for dev. If anyone search for 'how to make SSH tunnel': ssh -L 0.0.0.0:3308:localhost:3306 yourlinuxusername@127.0.0.1